# How to match elements after an element with certain content or attribute?

Tags: xpath

Simplified example

```
<td>caption</a>
<a id="tt-1">text1</a>
<a id="tt-2">text2</a>
<td>topics</td>
<a id="tt-3">text3</a>
<a id="tt-4">text4</a>
<a id="tt-5">text5</a>
```

What I need is to match all `a` elements below `<td>topics</td>`.
Note that there are plenty of elements between those elements in example. Also `<td>` may be enclosed into other elements.

My current real-world XPath expression looks like this

```
//a[contains(@id,'tt-')]
```

Updated to be closer to real-world

Another update to clarify.

Comment: Yes, the example is simplified in order to give idea what I want to achieve.

Comment: You may want to provide an example that's closer to your real-world markup to get more accurate answers :)

Comment: You've over-simplified it. I, for one, have no idea what you want to achieve. Which elements do (and don't!) you want to select, exactly? Besides, your input is not even well-formed XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your statement *"What I need is to match all a elements below `<td>topics</td>`"*

```
//td[.='topics']/a
```

I'm sure that's not the whole story, though.

Based on your updated example:

```
//a[starts-with(@id, 'tt-') and preceding-sibling::td[1] = 'topics']
```

Comment: The whole story is that between each line in my example there are plenty of other elements.

Comment: @Pablo So the second XPath expression in my answer is also not what you need?

Comment: None works. If `td[1]` implies to position, then this will not work, because number of td's before `<td>topics</td>` varies.

Comment: @Pablo: for the `preceding-sibling` axis the order of the elements is reversed. `preceding-sibling::td[1]` always means the first preceding sibling, i.e. the closest one. The expression reads *"all A elements whose ID starts with `tt-` and who directly follow a TD whose text is `topics`"*, which is what you seem to ask for.

Comment: @@Tomalak the reason I've simplified example is that it wouldn't be appropriate to paste the huge html here. From the other hand since I'm not so familiar with XPath I wasn't sure to what extent I can simplify it. Now going back I have to tell that `td` is enclosed into `tr` if it's important. I've updated my original post.

Comment: @Pablo See how simplifying an example can waste everybody's time? May I remind you that your markup is well-formed XML but not valid HTML.  Please post the HTML as you have it, because I'm still forced to guess.

Comment: simplifying usually save time. I couldn't guess. Here is full HTML http://pastebin.com/CgeKmu2F. `topics` correspond to `Топики`.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, simplifying means cutting down on the jQuery and removing all the HTML that has nothing to do with your question. There are still a few steps between *posting everything* and *posting not enough*. Having said that, try `//tr[td ='Топики']/following-sibling::tr[1]//a[starts-with(@id, 'tt-')]`

Comment: @Pablo Yes. Sure you've copied everything?

Comment: :so this gives me the first `a` element after `topics`

Comment: @Pablo: No. This gives you *every* `<a>` that is in the table row following the one that contains `Топики`. I'm *still* only guessing what you really want. To be honest, this is pretty frustrating.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you Tomalak and wasting your time, but in the first post I mentioned I want to collect all `a` elements after `Топики`. I'm testing this in the Firebug/Firepath and it gives me only first element following `Топики`.

Comment: This is screenshot of my original query, which selects all `a` elements. http://imgur.com/lDXc5

Comment: @Pablo: Try this, then: `//tr[td ='Топики']/following::a[starts-with(@id, 'tt-')]` - in the future please put some time into exactly defining what you need and writing it down. Interactive debugging via comments is not an ideal use of the site.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. You were very kind and patient. Your suggestions are well noted although that was not what I was doing.

Comment: @Pablo Don't get me wrong. Formal apologies are not necessary. If I had been angry I would not have continued. Anyway - is this what you need now? Note that this might catch `<a>` elements *after* the table.

Comment: Since after table `a` elements doesn't have `id` starting with `tt-` it will only catch what I need. So this is what I need. Thanks.